# Missing userId on url when using OpenWith feature in Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have 2 Google Drive accounts: A and B.

When A connect to an app over Google Chrome Store. I could use `Open With` and it redirect to expected url like this **http://example.com/state={ids: '123', action: 'open', userId: '12312adasd'}**

When I log into account B, the app will be listed on `Suggested App` when I use `Open With`. And it redirect to url with missing userId like this: **http://example.com/state={ids: '123', action: 'open', userId: '{userId}'}**

Any ideas or reference about this? Or bug from #google-drive-sdk ?

Comment: What happens if, for the mean time, you remove account A from browser and sign-in with only account B?

Comment: Same thing happened, the app still be listed on `Suggested App` and when I clicked on it, it redirected me to url missing userId